# CSS Gradient arrow shape with inner shadow and gradient border

Tags: css, button, gradient, css-shapes

I want to create a gradient arrow shape button with gradient border and 1px inner shadow from CSS.

I've created an image to show the button and the style rules:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```css
.button {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #D02180 !important;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f84aa4), to(#d02181));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f84aa4, #d02181);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f84aa4, #d02181);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#f84aa4, #d02181);
        background: linear-gradient(#f84aa4, #d02181);
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        border: 1px solid #ab1465;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
    }
```

```html
<a class="button">Next</a>
```

Cross-browser support is a main thing so it's also ok if everything can be done from CSS expect the gradient border. In this case the border will have one simple color — `#ab1465`.

The main problem starts with the gradient. I can make an arrow shape with the help of css pseudo elements, but I need a cross browser solution to have one continuous gradient for the whole arrow shape.

Comment: The main problem starts with the gradient. I can make an arrow shape with the help of css pseudo classes, but i can not make a cross browser solution to have continuous gradient for the hole arrow shape.

Comment: If the background color is solid you can use a pseudo element to fake the cuts. Otherwise you could look at CSS shapes, but you'll need to provide fallbacks. Most developers, when implementing something like this, would use an image

Comment: Image solution a bit of ,,old style" solution or not? Image spirte buttons looks ok on common PC but ugly on retina display. Double and triple sized image spirtes needed than. I want to avoid image solution. If CSS not work SVG sprite could be a solution. what do you think? I found a possible CSS way here: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/2mQjZ/59/light/ but it's not perfect in Safari(try to zoom!)

Comment: It won't be perfect in CSS in this point in time without CSS shapes  and a fallback

Answer (score 5):

### Gradient Arrow Button

#### Let's get creative!

This button has been created entirely with CSS — skew, border and gradient with pseudo elements. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

It looks nice zoomed in and doesn't break:

[image: zoomed screenshot]

This is the shape that creates it:

[image: Shape Creation]

The shape is cut off with `overflow: hidden` on the parent.

#### The CSS

- Create the angled shape and gradient with the `:before`.
- The inner shadow is created with the `:after` using a simple border
- The gradient is given an angle to match the direction of the pseudo elements rotation

Note the use of `transform: translateZ(0)`. This prevents a jagged appearance of the rotated pseudo element. Currently the pseudo element is placed underneath the text with `z-index: -1`.

### Complete Example

You will need to tinker with the fine details, but it should speak for itself. In order to take more text, the pseudo element with the gradient would need to be larger.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:300);
 a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2.4em;
  left: -20%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  background: #D02180 linear-gradient(130deg, rgba(248, 74, 165, 1) 30%, rgba(248, 74, 165, 1) 80%);
  transform: rotate(55deg) skewX(20deg) translateZ(0);
  z-index: -1;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: solid 1px #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px 0;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Next</a>
```