# CSS Gradient double-arrow shape with gradient background

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I saw this question and answer: [CSS Gradient arrow shape with inner shadow and gradient border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151167/css-gradient-arrow-shape-with-inner-shadow-and-gradient-border) and I'm looking to create the same thing but with an arrow on each side.

Here is what the final result would looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in 3 steps:

1. create a normal rectangular element with a background gradient (e.g. from orange to red)
2. create a pseudo element `::before` with a background color, the gradient is starting with (e.g. orange)
3. create a pseudo element `::after` with a background color, the gradient is ending with (e.g. red)

Now you just need to position the pseudo elements properly and use the `border` property to create [the triangle shape](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  height: 3em;
  min-width: 10em;
  line-height: 3em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, red);
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
}

div::before {
  left: -1em;
  border-right: 1em solid orange;
}

div::after {
  right: -1em;
  border-left: 1em solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>Exemple</div>
```

Comment: It will not beauty if I use gradient with direction (deg). exemple: linear-gradient(143deg, #EBD584 0%, #DDAE00 100%)

Answer (score 1):

What about a solution with only gradient and no pseudo element:

```css
.arrow {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 3em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top    left ,orange 50%,transparent 51%) top left    /20px 50%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,orange 50%,transparent 51%) bottom left /20px 50%,
    linear-gradient(to top    right,red    50%,transparent 51%) top right   /20px 50%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,red    50%,transparent 51%) bottom right/20px 50%,
    
    linear-gradient(to right, orange, red) 20px 0/calc(100% - 40px) 100% ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;   
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">Exemple</div>
<div class="arrow">work with <br>2 lines</div>
```

And here is another one with clip-path:

```css
.arrow {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 3em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, red);
  margin: 20px;
  clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 50%, 90% 100%, 10% 100%, 0 50%, 10% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">Exemple</div>
<div class="arrow">work with <br>2 lines</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can also write css without using gradient background
Step 1: write html

```
 <span class="right-arrow" style="
    background-color: red;
    width: 16%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
">
  Example
  </span>
```

Step 2: Write css

```
span{
    background-color: red;
    width: 180px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
}
span.right-arrow:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 21px solid transparent;
    border-left: 21px solid red;
    border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: -21px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Now it working fine

Comment: THank you, it's another great way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools has a great example of gradients in CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

background: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...)

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow);
```

For the shape of your div, W3Schools also has a great page for creating geometric shapes: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shapes.asp

But to paste the same code twice:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3em;
  min-width: 10em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, red);
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 2em;  
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
}

div::before {
  left: -1em;
  border-right: 1em solid orange;
}

div::after {
  right: -1em;
  border-left: 1em solid red;
}
```