# How to make a CSS gradient overlow in triangle div

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

How do I add a triangle div to a parent div with the same gradient as the parent? In the image below you can see what i mean. I want the grey triangle color be one with the gradient below. So the triangle has the same gradient. I want to do it only with HTML and css.

[image]

So I want it too look like this :

[image]

So the gradient will overflow in the triangle. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm thinking you should mask it: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49617542/8620333